# error: could not reach web server using genexus

Tags: genexus

I am currently using the genexus x evolution 2 software (trial version) to create a project. The problem is I cannot deploy my project due to that error(error: could not reach web server using genexus). I really need your help thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error in some moments when the deployment server is too busy or the upload bandwith of your internet connection is too slow.
Possible solutions are: a) Trying again some minutes later, b) downloading a new Trial version (*)that deploys to a faster cloud and also increases timeout (waits a little bit longer until server finishes the deployment and puts the app ready on air) c) contacting GeneXus support at www.gxtechnical.com/assistedsupport or trial@genexus.com
(*) GeneXus X Evolution 3 Trial version is about to be released by the end of june 2014 http://www.genexus.com/trial

Note that this error can also happen in the Full version of GeneXus, evolution 3 has improvements regarding this too. Refer to http://www.genexus.com/evolution3

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the IIS of your Windows.